# How can i send multiple variables from vb.net to php via post method?

Tags: php, vb.net

I found a code for how to send a post to php but i can send only one variable.
Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim postData = "msg=" & TextBox2.Text
    Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/msg.php")
    request.Method = "POST"

    Dim byteArray As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData)
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length

    Dim dataStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
    dataStream.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: What's the problem? If you need to send more, just call the sub multiple times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read some [documentation on how post works](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)#Use_for_submitting_web_forms), you will find that each key/value pair has to be separated by a &.

```
Dim postData = "msg=" & TextBox2.Text & "&msg2=" & TestBox3.Text
```

You still need to make sure your value are properly encoded.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim postData = "msg=" & TextBox2.Text & "&msg2=" & TestBox3.Text
```

This statement will still be considered as a single array. (NOT two different values)

or you can say different values in single string.

I guess in order to send multiple values, we must have to use array with (key->value) combination.

where `Key = msg` and value will be`textbox1.text` and so on.