# Trying to post web server PHP, multiple parameters not working VB

Tags: php, vb.net

Trying to POST to PHP to update database.

If I do a single parameter it works fine but if I try two parameters it is not working.

How do I post with two parameters?

VisualBasic Code

```
        Dim dateTime As DateTime = ReturnAsDateTime(thedate, thetime)
        Dim dateformat2 As String = "M/d/yyyy HH:mm"
        Dim dateformat3 As String = dateTime.ToString(dateformat2)
        Dim StudentNOString As String = thestudent.Number.ToString()
        Dim upString As String = "future01=" & dateformat3 & "StudentNumber=" & StudentNOString


        System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
        Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://example.com/tofilePHPfile.php")
        request.Method = "POST"
        Dim byteArray As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(upString)
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length
        Dim dataStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
        dataStream.Close()
        Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream()
        Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)
        Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
        reader.Close()
        dataStream.Close()
        response.Close()
        MsgBox(responseFromServer)
```

PHP Code

```
<?php

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}


if (isset ($_POST["future01"]) && isset ($_POST["StudentNumber"])){
    $future01 = $_POST["future01"];
    $StudentNumber = $_POST["StudentNumber"];
} else {
    $future01 = "testfortestfortest";
    $StudentNumber = "1";
    echo "not working";
}

$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE pushtable SET future01=? WHERE StudentNumber=?");

$stmt->bind_param('ss', $future01,$StudentNumber);

$stmt->execute();

echo $future01;
//echo $StudentNumber;
echo "New records created successfully";

$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
?>
```

There is something wrong with this line I think as the PHP is not posting it correctly.

```
   Dim upString As String = "future01=" & dateformat3 & "StudentNumber=" & StudentNOString
```

I have tried dozens of different ways and tried to search for my problem but I cannot seem to find an answer. The PHP works perfectly well from IOS objective-c code. So, I think my problem is in the Visual Basic Code.

future01 and StudentNumber are not being recognized individually when POST occurs.

These are some of the pages I have looked at:

[How to send and recieve data from Visual Basic to PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37770767/how-to-send-and-recieve-data-from-visual-basic-to-php)

https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=131236&seqNum=7

[POST Request using VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47027915/post-request-using-vbscript)

[Multiple key/value pairs in HTTP POST where key is the same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614762/multiple-key-value-pairs-in-http-post-where-key-is-the-same-name)

[How can i send multiple variables from vb.net to php via post method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30465184/how-can-i-send-multiple-variables-from-vb-net-to-php-via-post-method)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)#Use_for_submitting_web_forms

Comment: What kind of database is it? MS Sql Server, Oracle, MySql?

Comment: I'm not a web dev, but I can clearly see you don't have any delimiter in your parameters: `Dim upString As String = "future01=" & dateformat3 & "StudentNumber=" & StudentNOString` This will produce a results such as `future01=9/29/2021 10:00StudentNumber=123`

Comment: @HardCode - Sorry for the late reply. I didn't receive any notifications from StackOverflow so I thought no one had replied. Yes, that was the issue! Thank you for helping out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a delimiter between your parameters. This code...

```
Dim upString As String = "future01=" & dateformat3 & "StudentNumber=" & StudentNOString
```

...will produce output like this:

> future01=9/29/2021 10:00StudentNumber=123